# Cryptography for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios5, encryption, smime, zimbra

I'm trying to make a software for iPhone to connect to one secured mail server and does the basic cryptography function. It would be encryption-signing and decryption.

I found a few frameworks like http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ that can be used even for iOS programming but according to http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4979# iOS 5 has the support, so it would be easier to use the iOS feature rather than the third-party code, right?

But not all of users would able to setup secure mails. I was thinking of writing an app that just setup a mail account on the user's iPhone.

This application just needs to get the username and password (remember I want it for one single server) and does the configuration, like the things that was described in above link; is it possible? If yes how? Does http://www.rootmanager.com/iphone-ota-configuration/iphone-ota-setup-with-signed-mobileconfig.html work fine for my requirements?

> ***Additional info:***

1. Zimbra 5 is working in the server side!
2. No one here is expert on iOS. We have written the server code in Java and also some applications for the client side but now we are forced to add support for iPhone!
3. Feel free to ask for additional information!

Comment: Some questions you should answer: 1) are you building a new mail appications / why is the built-in apple mail application not suitable 2) what protocols are you encrypting (e.g. imap/s smtp/s or s/mime)? 3) why does your application need to handle the username - is it ok if iphone settings handles that?

Comment: A bit off the point, but be aware that technically, if you live in the US or are a US citizen then it's against the law to ship "unapproved" encryption technology to certain countries.  For this reason it's generally best to use encryption technology embedded in the phone (and already vetted) than to use some open source stuff you got off the net and compiled in yourself.

Comment: @AlexBrown , Im using S/Mime but my p7m file is not an standard one, I wrote the same app for blackberry and some other mail clients, iPhone should be able to sign, encrypt, decrypt  their messages, the message from bb contains some none encrypted info together with encrypted data. This app should work in an organization which every one have the public key and they should be able to send message to each other easily:D If the Iphone mail app can do the same thing it would be perfect but can it??!!!

Comment: BTW, @HotLicks thanks for sharing but i'm not in US.

Comment: The iPhone mail app can certainly use s/mime to encrypt and decrypt email messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 'install' mail settings on a user's phone using Profiles generated by [the iPhone configuration utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466)

S/mime keys for send mail to other users are distributed via exchange or by receiving mail from other users. [apple blurb](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4979)

---

The Apple link you give is for sending encrypted emails; which is different from securing the connection to the mail-server.  The iphone is capable of both.

Comment: Actually I'm using djigzo to generate certificates and was enable to import the key inside myphone.

Comment: But, I can't open the decrypted messsage sent by my signedencrypted mails by other users sent by my application!

Comment: if you are using the standard apple mail, look in the settings for the account and activate s/mime, then select the certificate you installed (also check the certificate capabilities)

Comment: it doesn't decrypt my signed-encrypted email

Comment: Have you installed the certificate?  try emailing yourself the certificate, then open the certificate to install it.  For decryption you will then need to supply the password to install the private key.

Comment: Dear Alex, yr helps are truly appreciated, as I mentioned the black berry mails won't be oppen, FYI, I'm using Bouncy Castle API

Comment: Are you able to use the iPhone certificates to encrypt or decrypt mail sent from the phone other than blackberry messages? Can you send a screenshot of your s/mime configuration page on the phone?

Comment: yes, I can open the mails from Iphone to Iphone but not from Djigzo and Bouncy Castle

Comment: Can your desktop client open the encrypted emails from blackberry and iPhone?

Comment: I wrote that client, based on zimbra (as a zimlet), as I mentioned blackberry is fully supported and I can open the Iphone files with a-bit of changes, we want Iphone to be able to open our none-standard (Djigzo based) smime mails to have a comprehensive secure mail services... Also this user-profile based security sucks, we need our clients to be able to use all their colleagues public keys and sent to them.

Comment: The profile base installation is just for your key.  See your link http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4979 for how other users keys are managed in apple mail.  I don't know how you plan to distribute public keys.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16548/discussion-between-alex-brown-and-nil-null)